# Indexing to 3d lookup-table by color.rgb gives black screen

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, lookup-tables

**[SOLVED]** Not sure how, but currently can't reproduce the problem.

---

Trying to remap rgb values using a 3d lookup table.

**The vertex shader:** (if relevant)

```
void main()
{
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
}
```

**The fragment shader**

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler3D lut;

void main()
{
    vec3 color = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture3D(lut, vec3(.5, .5, .5)).xyz, .5);
    // gl_FragColor = vec4(texture3D(lut, vec3(color.r, .5, .5)).xyz, .5);
}
```

`lut` is a 32x32x32 texture, full of red pixels (for testing).
`tex` is a 1280x720 texture.
Both use `rgb` as internal pixel format.

When **indexing with immediate values** to the LUT (the uncommented line):
I see a **proper result** of a red screen with 50% alpha.

When the **indexing is related to `color.rgb`** (the commented line):
I see the **whole screen black**.

I tried `vec3(color.r / 1000.0, .5, .5)` as well,
just to make sure the `x` index will be lower than `1`.
That didn't help.

**So how do I properly access the lut3d using my current tex2d rgb values?**

Comment: Is the typo just a transcription error? `gl_FragColor` has a capital `F`.

Comment: It's also `texture3D` instead of `texture3d` for the function name.

Comment: Thanks, fixed in the question. In the code I was using the proper capitalizations, though.

Comment: Can you try something like `0.5 + color.r`? Could be that `color.r` is always 0.0, which would potentially give you black depending on how the sampling parameters for the 3D texture are set.

Comment: Testing the code again (different computer). `texture3D(lut, color).xyz` just works now. Any chance it behaves differently on different GPUs?

Comment: The shader code itself looks fine to me after the typos are fixed. I originally suspected a problem with your texture setup. But that shouldn't be platform dependent either. What version of OpenGL are you using? Without a `#version`, these would be treated as version `110`, which corresponds to OpenGL 2.0.

Comment: @RetoKoradi It is possible that the texture setup was done wrong. I've had a few attempts and performed changed in the code and the shader (which looks just about the same eventually), so I can't really tell how the code looked at first. But now the problem is solved and all is good :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like Compiler error on non OpenGL side of your App , have seen this few times usually delete of temp/state files and recompile helps or just swapping few lines of code or adding removing  empty line to code helps (or turning off/on the IDE). (Have seen this behavior on both Borland/Embarcadero and MSVCpp compilers but it happens rarely unless you compile really big projects...Usually memory leaks in App make this happen by corrupting the IDE memory)